# Server validation not working as expected while clicking submit Button very fast

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am checking duplicate name validation in server function in .netcore webapi project, but when clicking save button fastly from UI, server process parallel requests and enters same name in database. I know that this can be avoided setting constraints in Database, but Is there any solution other than this, because when we are dealing with a huge logic validation in server before save in other functions so same situation can happen.

```
public async Task<ReturnMessageMain> Create(CreateOrEditMainCategoryDto input)
        {
            if (_mainCategoryRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.MainGroup == input.MainGroup.Trim()).Count() > 0)
            {
                throw new UserFriendlyException("Main Category already exists");
            }

            var mainCategory = ObjectMapper.Map<MainCategory>(input);


            int id = await _mainCategoryRepository.InsertAndGetIdAsync(mainCategory);

            if (id > 0)
            {
                return new ReturnMessageMain()
                {
                    Id = id,
                    Code = input.MainGroupCode,
                    Message = "Saved Successfully"

                };

            }
            else
            {
                return new ReturnMessageMain()
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    // Code = input.MainGroupCode,
                    Message = "Please try again"

                };
            }
        }
```

when user click multiple times save button then create function is called several times, this causes the issue, we can disable submit button but this is only an approach from client side, how can we handle this from server side

Comment: Even if there is a way to stop this at a single server level, consider a cluster of independent application servers where each parallel request is handled by a different server. The only reliable solution is a unique constraint in the database.

Comment: You may need to look at the `lock` statement provided by .net framework
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

we use it in an e-commerce site

Comment: @ Wiktor Zychla but consider a situation of checking stock of items in database, then how can we deal this.

Comment: You should 100% check this on the server AND client side so even if the user hits the button and bypasses the JS validation the server will catch it and return the appropriate error.

Comment: @scgough I am checking in server but issue is parallel request.

Comment: @rjs123431: `lock` doesn't work when two different application servers process requests in parallel. `lock` only works on a single server.

Comment: @Nighil: first, you query the database. Then, if the database says the record doesn't exists, you insert. But, if there is a unique constraint, you still can get an error indicating that inserting is not possible. This happens when two parallel requests are interlaced. This case is handled in the very same way you handle an already existing item.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla I just posted an example scenario, but this can happen in stock checking also consider there are 5 items in stock two request came at a time, first request check items in stock it pass validation but save doesn't happen at that time second request also occurs parallel passes validation and if save occurs for two requests then sales occurs for 10 items and only 5 will be available in stock

Comment: @Nighil: this is easily prevented by a database constraint, the second transaction will fail as the database won't allow a below-zero value of the stock. Yet another perfect example where concurrency issues can be prevented with a database constraint.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla , In Inventory stock is not reduced when purchase done, another new entry with -1 or qty purchased (that will be negative) will be added as a new row, so how can we set constraint there?